# set of passwords in arrays, the user only has 3 chances

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make an array of passwords looping for the user to be redirected to another site. After 3 mistakes the user cannot try again. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
<form>
<label>Please enter Password</label>
<input type="text" id="Pass" />
<input type="button" value="go" onClick="check()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
var password = ["123","456","789"]
for(a=0;a=password.length;a++)
{
    if (user="password")
{
document.location.href="http://yahoo.com";
}
else 
{
alert("wrong password");
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: That if statement also doesn't make any sense, it assigns `user` to `789` which is always truthy.

Comment: you are right the funtion was not there, i edited it more, and i have this, but it still doesnt work:(

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling a function `check` from the `onclick` event, you need a function by that name in your code.

When calling the `check` function you can pass along the value from the text box, so that the function can use it to check against the items in the array.

In your code the condition for the loop is wrong. Using `a=password.length` means that the loop won't run at all. The loop runs as long as the condition is true, it's not used to mark the end of the loop.

Use the `==` operator to check if two values are equal (the `=` operator is for assignment). Use `password[a]` to get the item from the array which has the index from the variable `a`.

In the loop you should only check for when the strings are equal. If you have an `else` case there, it will tell you that the password is wrong for every password that didn't match. Use `return` to exit from the function when you have set the location.

After the loop you know that none of the password matches, so then you know that the password was wrong.

```
<body>
  <form>
    <label>Please enter Password</label>
    <input type="text" name="Pass" />
    <input type="button" value="go" onclick="check(this.form.Pass.value)"/>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var password = ["123","456","789"];

  function check(pass) {
    for(a = 0; a < password.length; a++) {
      if (pass == password[a]) {
        document.location.href="http://yahoo.com";
        return;
      }
    }
    alert("wrong password");
  }

  </script>
</body>
```